# Does props.history.listen in React Router need to be cleaned up in useEffect? If so, what is the right way to do it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement something that requires listening to the location.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        props.history.listen(location => {
            // do stuff here
        });
        return () => {
            props.history.listen(location => {
                // now stop doing stuff
            });
        };
    }, []);
```

I have seen reference to `unlisten()` but it's not backed up with a lot of upvotes, and if I do `console.log(props.history.unlisten())` it comes back as `not a function`

This is done in App.js.  I am assuming this should be cleaned up, but I'm not sure it actually needs to be.

Does it need to be cleaned up?  If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

The return value from props.history.listen is a function. Calling that function will do the teardown, so you just need to return it:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = props.history.listen(location => {
    // do stuff here
  });
  return unlisten;
}, []);
```

Or:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return props.history.listen(location => {
    // do stuff here
  });
}, []);
```